# Generate the JAXB classes from XSD containing namespace in element name

Tags: xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, xjc

I am trying to generate the JAXB class file from below XSD

```
     <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"   version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="comp:myItems">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="style" type="xsd:string" />
              </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
       </xsd:schema>
```

however I get below error while generating the JAXB class file

C:\JAVA\jdk1.6.0_26\bin>xjc.exe myFile.xsd

> parsing a schema...
>   [ERROR] s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'type' in element 'element'. Recorded reason: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'comp:myItems' as a QName: the prefix 'comp' is not declared.
>     line 2 of file:/C:/JAVA/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/myFile.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.

*Error I am getting because the element name is comp:myItems*.

Is there any way to generate the JAXB class file from above XSD?
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element name specified in the XML Schema must not contain a colon (`:`).  If you want the element to be namespace qualified you need to specify a `targetNamespace` on the `schema` element.  You will also need to declare this namespace.

```
<xsd:schema 
    ...
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/foo"
    xmlns:comp="http://www.example.com/foo">
```